# uEFI Remote Mangement

Tags: remote-access, firmware, uefi

Is there a sane method to set uEFI settings (for machines with no OS) from a remote machine? I've just spent *hours* for changing the boot order of a handful of machines. The extended boot up times for uEFI machines are horrible!

Comment: I'd like to know too - Dell's DMC was supposed to get uEFI remote config for their uEFI systems (the 11G server line, R210, 310, 410 etc) by the end of '09 but I haven't seen it yet.

Comment: There is no industry standard way to remotely configure UEFI firmware.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is, depending on your vendor.

For example, for IBM IMM-based servers:

```
$ asu set uEFI.QuietBoot Enable --host IMMIP --user USERID --password PASSW0RD
```

Comment: That is ASU talking to IMM or RSA - not generic enough. I hoped for general method for uEFI-based systems.

Comment: Do all UEFI-based systems have any kind of remote management? Not necessarily. Therefore, a generic solution does not exist. But we can enumerate the methods for various vendors' platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange this one hasn't been answered yet. Have you tried `efibootmgr -v` yet? It should let you list and manage entries.

https://www.makeuseof.com/how-to-view-and-change-boot-sequence-in-linux-terminal/

Or if you truly need to do it headless for a machine with no OS you may need to use Intel's defunct (compromised) AMT or some component of Management Engine. That's assuming IPMI is not available.